# Android Studio on a hardware that does not support virtualization technology

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Android Studio on Ubuntu Linux on a machine that does not support virtualization technology. Android Studio demands KVM to be installed to run emulators, but I cannot do so due to the previously mentioned hardware limitation.

Are there any options for me to overcome this issue (using the same hardware)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to run the ARM system images, which unfortunately will be super-slow, but it will work. As of now, you can't run x86 system images on an x86 platform at all without KVM. This will be true of anyone running an AMD processor; HAXM is Intel-specific.

You can also try the Genymotion emulator, which works on many platforms that can't run HAXM.

Answer (score 1):

KVM should not be necessary for running an ARM emulator, only for x86 (see the documentation for [VM acceleration](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration)).

Have you tried creating an AVD using the ARM EABI instead of the Intel one?

Answer (score 0):

### Virtualization extension requirements

> Your computer's processor must support one of the following virtualization extension technologies:
>
> - Intel Virtualization Technology Extensions (**VT, VT-x, vmx**)
> - AMD Virtualization Extensions (**AMD-V, SVM**)
>
> Most modern processors support these virtualization extensions. If you
> are not sure if your processor supports these extensions, check the
> specifications on the manufacturer's site. If it doesn't support any,
> you won't be able to use VM acceleration.

The ideal would be to use Android Studio in an [ARM processor](https://www.xataka.com/ordenadores/comienza-nueva-era-mac-arm-apple-que-podemos-esperar-futuros-imac-macbook) so that the emulator runs natively.

GL

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#dependencies)