# A suitable machine for Android development now?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

Although experienced with development using Eclipse, after a short break I realise that my current machine (Vista, 3GB, unable to support virtualisation)is inadequate to migrate to Android Studio and the latest SDK.

I was contemplating a Linux laptop (ASUS X555LA Laptop, Intel Core i7, 8GB RAM) and assuming I could install Ubuntu 15 on it, would it make a reasonably quick Android Studio development machine?

I would much appreciate any answers from experienced A. Studio/Ubuntu programmers.

Comment: 8gb RAM is ok but you can never have enough RAM. The more the better

Comment: This is not really on-topic for Stack Overflow. That being said, I am typing this on an Ubuntu notebook, Core i7 (turbo boost to ~3.4GHz), 8GB RAM, and an SSD, and it is a fine Android development machine.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that's what I wanted to know. I realised the question would attract a few close votes, as it's bordering on off topic but not quite o.t. as I was truly stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you'll get an adequate answer for this, so I'll throw my hat in the ring. I personally believe virualization is not the downfall of your current machine. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428905/android-studio-on-a-hardware-that-does-not-support-virtualization-technology) post suggests that you do not need virtualization other than for faster emulators, since you probably have a physical Android device for testing, this is likely not as critical.

I Google'd the Laptop you want to upgrade to (it was i5), and has virualization, so it would be better in that regard.

I currently use a rather high end pc (i7 4770k, 16gb ram, SSD drive) and I would not consider Android Studio to be "fast". The continuous build times are very noticeable. Granted, the upgrade would perform a lot better; but if you do upgrade, don't expect a seamless dev environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for that information. Google searches hadn't helped me at all. Whilst I do have a physical device, it only runs Jelly Bean. I am interested in seeing the new Lollipop and hence my query about virtualisation (for emulators) I can't afford to buy a new tablet/phone every time the SDK is updated.