# HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode error in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using Android studio 1.1.0 and still I'm a beginner to Android studio.What I have done is just set a background image and I was trying to run the app but sometimes emulator is not displaying but when I tried to run the app several times emulator was displayed but it only shows the word Android.It is not displaying anything else.I know this question has repeated on stackoverflow but none of them gave me a solution so I posted my question.
and below messages are shown in output window

```
C:\Users\S_programmer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86
emulator: device fd:640
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 1024 MB
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

And also my emulator is very slow I have to wait till it comes for about 10 or 15 minutes.How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio on a hardware that does not support virtualization technology](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428905/android-studio-on-a-hardware-that-does-not-support-virtualization-technology)